# Convert a text file to a matrix

Tags: python, file, matrix

I've been trying to convert this time of data from a file into a matrix.

```
101 Bob 10
104 Lob 5
103 Dob 9
109 Dobby 4
```

The best thing I can do is transform it in a list such as this one.

```
['101 Bob 10', '104 Lob 5', '103 Dob 9', '109 Dobby 4']
```

The question is how can I transpose the file into a matrix?

Comment: When you say 'matrix' do you mean a list of lists, or something like a `numpy` array? Or perhaps a Python `array`? Also, you're really just asking how to `.split()` a string?

Comment: You might be looking for `dataframes` not matrices. Check out `pandas`. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/01_table_oriented.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a matrix among the native types of Python, hence the comments.

To read the file into a 2D NumPy array, try

```py
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt('filename', dtype=str)
print(data)
print(data.shape)
print(data[0, 1])
```

Note that all elements will be `str`s, so you will have to convert the numbers into proper `int`s afterwards (if needed).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for a solution such as this.

First open the file and read all lines ("with" will handle closing the file, the option 'r' ensures the file is opened for reading only).

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

At this stage all file content is in memory kept by the *lines* variable in a list, each item of the list is one line from the file.

Then take each line and split it using spaces as delimiter.
The split function returns a list of strings, e.g. ['101', 'Bob', '10']. The split result needs to be placed in an outer list to emulate a matrix. These are two ways to do this:

```
output = []
for line in lines
    output.append(line.split(' ')
```

alternatively, you can use the condensed form to replace all three lines above.

```
output = [item.split(' ') for item in input]
```

Please note that as coded the entire file has to fit in memory, the line split only works if space can be used as delimiter.

```
print(output)
print(output[0][1])
```

The second print shows how a *matrix* can be emulated. The results are:

```
[['101', 'Bob', '10'], ['104', 'Lob', '5'], ['103', 'Dob', '9'], ['109', 'Dobby', '4']]
Bob
```

Comment: While this code *may* answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: @matineau, I added tutorial-like explanation to the answer

Comment: Much better IMO (although I'm not sure you needed to take things quite that far…)